# Is it Possible to update body of file before uploading in salesforce using trigger?

Tags: trigger, files

Need to update the body of the file before uploading into salesforce.
Here is the sample code i am using it for updating attachment

```
trigger SetTitleToAttachment on Attachment(before insert) {
    for (Attachment att: Trigger.new) {
        if (att.ContentType == 'text/plain') {
            String s = att.body.toString();
            att.body = blob.valueOf('Text Encryption\n' + s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes , I have to add some custom test.I have been using this for uploading attchment. the same thing i am trying to implement it while uploading files....Here is the code i am using it for attachment.

Comment: have been trying this but couldn't get, please share if you have any sample code to for the same or give some idea to achieve this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked on this and finally got the solution(trigger) which will help us to update the file before uploading. We can update title,body etc....

```
trigger setcontentdoclink on ContentDocumentLink(before insert) {

    ContentVersion cont = new ContentVersion();
    ContentVersion cont1 = new ContentVersion();



    for (ContentDocumentLink cd: Trigger.new) {

        if (cd.ContentDocumentId != null) {
            cont.ContentDocumentId = cd.ContentDocumentId;
        }
        cont1 = [SELECT VersionData FROM ContentVersion where ContentDocumentId =: cd.ContentDocumentId limit 1];


    }
    cont.PathOnClient = 'file_' + Datetime.now().getTime() + '.txt';
    string docbody = 'Eventdex Enchryption\n' + cont1.VersionData.toString();
    cont.VersionData = Blob.valueOf(docbody);
    cont.Origin = 'H';
    insert cont;

}
```